# Determining properties to serialize in Json.Net based on user

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I am creating a ASP MVC Web API. I now want to determine what properties to serialize of a object based on the user that is doing the request. The ApiController knows the user. And based on the user I have a function that returns a string array with the property names the user has rights to on the model.

How can I pass the user to the ContractResolver so it only affects the current request and not possible simultanious requests from other users?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a custom `ContractResolver`

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
                new UserClass() {ID=666, Name="john", SurName="doe"},
                new JsonSerializerSettings() { ContractResolver = new CustomContractResolver(new[]{"ID", "SurName"}) }
            );
```

in this example, output json will only include `ID` and `SurName` (not `Name`)

```
public class UserClass
{
    public int ID { set; get; }
    public string Name {set; get;}
    public string SurName { set; get; }
}

public class CustomContractResolver : Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver
{
    IEnumerable<string> _allowedProps = null;

    public CustomContractResolver(IEnumerable<string> allowedProps)
    {
        _allowedProps = allowedProps;
    }

    protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        return _allowedProps.Select(p=>new JsonProperty() {
            PropertyName = p,
            PropertyType = type.GetProperty(p).PropertyType,
            Readable = true,
            Writable = true,
            ValueProvider = base.CreateMemberValueProvider(type.GetMember(p).First())
        } ).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: This resolver code looks good, but the OP is using Web API.  With Web API, you configure the resolver when the application starts, then the requests happen later (the Web API framework handles serialization behind the scenes using the resolver).  As I understand the question, the list of allowed properties can change for each request based on user, so I think he is trying to figure out how he can get this list into the resolver for each different request.

Comment: @BrianRogers You might be right, in that case a thread-static variable can be used.  `[ThreadStatic] static IEnumerable<string> allowedProps ;`

Comment: @L.B That was exactly what I was after, I'm going to try it this instant :).

Answer (score 1):

Can't you create a new Contract resolver for every request your api receives?
As long as you create a new instance per request the contract resolvers will never be in conflict with each other.
Code could look like this :

```
var resolver = new MyUserBasedResolver(userObject);
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
        product,
        Formatting.Indented,
        new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = resolver }
        );
```

Comment: OK, but how would you do that within the Web API framework?  I think that is the real question here.