# Deseralization of JSON to VB.NET object getting NULL

Tags: json, vb.net, deserialization, json-deserialization

I have a JSON string that i'm trying to deserialize in a VB.NET object but i'm getting nothing but nothing/nulls. Below is the VB.net code i'm doing the deserlization. The object, and the string version of what i'm sending to the deserialization, and what i'm getting back. I should be getting back what i'm passing. Here is some info from Chrome console that might be helpful. http://screencast.com/t/qBaXhvAS. The red are what i'm passing, the yellows are what i'm getting back.

Thanks!

**VB.NET**

```
    Dim serializer As New JavaScriptSerializer()
    Dim response As IMSClassLibrary.PhotoModelManagerCL.objOutfitModel = serializer.Deserialize(Of IMSClassLibrary.PhotoModelManagerCL.objOutfitModel)(JSON)
return response
```

**VB.NET Object**

```
<Serializable()> Public Class objOutfitModel
        Private _OutfitModelKey As String
        Public Property OutfitModelKey() As String
            Get
                Return _OutfitModelKey
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _OutfitModelKey = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Private _ModelFirstName As String
        Public Property ModelFirstName() As String
            Get
                Return _ModelFirstName
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _ModelFirstName = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Private _ModelLastName As String
        Public Property ModelLastName() As String
            Get
                Return _ModelLastName
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _ModelLastName = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Private _M3SizeCode As String
        Public Property M3SizeCode() As String
            Get
                Return _M3SizeCode
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _M3SizeCode = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Private _Girth As String
        Public Property Girth() As String
            Get
                Return _Girth
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _Girth = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Private _ShoeSize As String
        Public Property ShoeSize() As String
            Get
                Return _ShoeSize
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _ShoeSize = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Private _AddressLine1 As String
        Public Property AddressLine1() As String
            Get
                Return _AddressLine1
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _AddressLine1 = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Private _AddressLine2 As String
        Public Property AddressLine2() As String
            Get
                Return _AddressLine2
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _AddressLine2 = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Private _City As String
        Public Property City() As String
            Get
                Return _City
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _City = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Private _State As String
        Public Property State() As String
            Get
                Return _State
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _State = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Private _Zip As String
        Public Property Zip() As String
            Get
                Return _Zip
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _Zip = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Private _ModelNotes As String
        Public Property ModelNotes() As String
            Get
                Return _ModelNotes
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _ModelNotes = value
            End Set
        End Property

    End Class
```

**JSON** 
what i'm passing and what i should be getting back once 'deserialized'

```
{"_AddressLine1":"123 arsenal","_AddressLine2":"apt 1","_City":"saint louis","_Girth":"14","_M3SizeCode":"71","_ModelFirstName":"joshua","_ModelLastName":"harris","_ModelNotes":"testing 123","_OutfitModelKey":0,"_ShoeSize":"20","_State":"ME","_Zip":"63031"}
```

what i'm actually getting back

```
{"_AddressLine1":null,"_AddressLine2":null,"_City":null,"_Girth":null,"_M3SizeCode":null,"_ModelFirstName":null,"_ModelLastName":null,"_ModelNotes":null,"_OutfitModelKey":null,"_ShoeSize":null,"_State":null,"_Zip":null}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON has your field names prefixed with underscores, e.g. `_AddressLine1`, which corresponds to the member variable names in your class.  However, these are `Private`, but the `JavaScriptSerializer` will only use `Public` member variables or properties.  So, you can either change your JSON to drop the underscore prefix (in which case the `Public` properties will be used) or make the member variables `Public`.

There may be a way to override this with `JavaScriptSerializer`.  Also, it looks like if you switched to [JSON.net](http://james.newtonking.com/json) things make be [more flexible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24107081/2278086).

Comment: OMGGG!!! thank you so much!! Changed the private to public and it worked! BEAUTIFUL! 

THANKS!