# Troubleshooting SignalR Serialization

Tags: json.net, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I have the following code:

```
 try {
            _hubConnection = new HubConnection(_baseUrl);
            _hubConnection.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
            _hubConnection.CookieContainer.Add(_cookie);
            _hubProxy = _hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("appHub");
            _hubConnection.Start().Wait();
        }
 catch (Exception e) {
            Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(new Exception("Serialization error [hubConnection] - " + e.Message + ", " + e.InnerException.Message + ", " + e.ToString()));
        }
```

Usually, this works.  Every once in a while, I get a random serialization error though:

```
Serialization error [hubConnection] - One or more errors occurred., Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0., System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.
 at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue()
 at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.Read()
 at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.ReadForType(JsonReader reader, JsonContract contract, Boolean hasConverter)
 at
```

This `Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <` seems very difficult to reproduce, and I don't know how to get detailed information around this.  I do have this configured:

```
        var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration { EnableDetailedErrors = true };
        app.MapSignalR(hubConfiguration);
```

Does anyone know what might be causing this, or how I might go about troubleshooting?

Full trace:

```
System.Exception: Messaging Error [hubConnection]    at App.Services.NotificationService.SignalObjectToUser(Object data, String username, Boolean isTypingNotification)    at App.Services.NotificationService.MessageSentNotification(User toUser, Message message, Int32 conversationId, Boolean isOnline)    at App.Services.MessageService.SendMessage(MessageDto message, FStopContext altContext)    at App.ApiControllers.MessageController.SendMessage(MessageDto message) at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )    at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)    at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)    at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.d__0.MoveNext()
```

Comment: The error message **Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.** almost certainly means that XML was received instead of JSON.

Comment: @dbc From where and why though?

Comment: This I don't know -- that's why it's a comment not an answer.  Maybe an exception thrown on the server side?

Comment: @dbc - this is serverside and the only exception thrown gives me the details I pasted above.  That is thrown from the `catch`.

Comment: I reckon it would be useful to find out exactly what XML is being sent.  However, I don't know SignalR well.  1) That traceback seems incomplete.  Can you share the full traceback?  2) Is there any way to get access to the `JsonTextReader` being used to deserialize the current object, similar to how the `JsonTextWriter` is made available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37448604)?  3) If worst came to worst, could you build your own version of Json.NET and deploy it on the server?

Comment: @dbc full trace pasted.  Seeing the XML would be amazing - but I just don't know how :(.  Obviously I'd rather not build another deserializer.  There HAS to be a way to gain verbosity here.

Comment: You don't have the full traceback that includes the call to Json.NET, do you?  It looks like the first traceback you posted (the one that includes `JsonSerializerInternalReader.ReadForType`) has been truncated.

Comment: @dbc - thanks for the continued help here.  This is just the full exception thrown by .NET - how can I get that for you?  I don't believe I truncated anything.

Comment: To me it looks like its getting ahead of itself, its trying to send a call through the hub that has not yet had its message created. I would look for situations where an empty message is being sent

Comment: Can you enable tracing on the client side : `hubConnection.TraceLevel = TraceLevels.All;
hubConnection.TraceWriter = Console.Out;`. Reference : http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/testing-and-debugging/enabling-signalr-tracing

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things I would try before digging deeper into the content being transmitted:

1. Set up the hub connection without a cookie container. This would narrow down whether this is causing the issue.
2. Rather than using .Wait() on your hub connection, try use an async/await function. I seem to recall having a similar exception when I was using Wait() in the past.

Post back your results.