# Trying to convert List<object> to an array

Tags: c#, arrays, json

I have a List of type "Employee" Class object which contains employees details retrieved from the database.

All data are being retrieved to the list successfully, but when I try to convert the list to a JSON array object, I'm getting strange errors.

I've used two methods to accomplish that, but neither of them worked.

Here is the full beind-code:

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

..

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string getRecords()
{
    SqlConnection con;
    SqlCommand cmd;
    SqlDataReader reader;
    List<Employee> dataRows = new List<Employee>();

    con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=\"C:\\Users\\Shebel Ali\\Desktop\\SampleDB.mdf\";Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
    con.Open();
    cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "select * from Employee";

    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    int i = 1;

    for (i=0; i<reader.FieldCount; i++)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(reader.GetName(i));
    }


    while (reader.Read())
    {
        Employee getEmp = new Employee(reader.GetValue(0).ToString(), reader.GetValue(1).ToString(), reader.GetValue(2).ToString(), reader.GetValue(3).ToString(), reader.GetValue(4).ToString(), reader.GetValue(5).ToString(), reader.GetValue(6).ToString());
        dataRows.Add(getEmp);
    }

    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();        
    string resp = js.Serialize(dataRows);

    return resp;
}
```

And here is the Employee class:

```
[Serializable]
public class Employee: ISerializable
{
    private string empID { get; set; }
    private string fname { get; set; }
    private string lname { get; set; }
    private string address { get; set; }
    private string phone { get; set; }
    private string deptID { get; set; }
    private string email { get; set; }

    public Employee(string empID, string fname, string lname,string address, string phone, string deptID, string email)
    {
        this.empID = empID;
        this.fname = fname;
        this.lname = lname;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.deptID = deptID;
        this.email = email;
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

this code returned me an empty JSON array object:

> [{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]

I've tried also using this:

```
var string jsonOb = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataRows);
```

but when an error pops up:

> <'object' does not contain a definition for 'SerializeObject' and no
>   extension method 'SerializeObject' accepting a first argument of type
>   'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?)>

I've tried to reinstall the Newtonsoft package several times but I'm getting the same issue.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Judging by the error you're getting, that sounds like you've got a member called `JsonConvert` of type `object` somewhere... a [mcve] will definitely help.

Comment: Does the Employee class implements the Serializable interface?

Comment: @Genkus yes it does

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If Newton.Json returns [{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}], it means the object are serialized, but it cannot see any property to be serialized, I guess because they are private?

Only public properties or fields can be serialized by default.

**Edit after @Sinatr comment:**
You can also explicitly add *[JsonPropertyAttribute](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonPropertyName.htm)* to private field/property to serialize it (or use custom contract resolver).

Comment: Thanks!!. Actually yes the properties where private, stupid mistake, thanks very much

Comment: *"Only public properties or fields can be serialized"* is wrong. You can explicitly add [`JsonPropertyAttribute`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/t_newtonsoft_json_jsonpropertyattribute.htm) to private field/property to serialize it (or use custom [contract resolver](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24107081/1997232)).