# Cannot deserialize type without setter

Tags: c#, xml

I have binary serialized objects in database. They are serialized with protobuf.
Now I need to generate some viewer to see the content of Database.
So, i read stream from database and deserialized it back to the objects.
It works and the result is list of objects:

```
var dbData = readData(someType);//it is IList collection
```

Now, I would like to save this list of objects to file to see the content of database. I thought it would be the best to save it to xml. So, i have tried:

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(dbData.GetType());
```

But i get an error:  Cannot deserialize type 'My.Entities.IdBase' because it contains property 'Key' which has no public setter.

What now? I can't change the class definitions to have setters. 
Should i save objects to json or plain text instead? Or should i extract all properties and values and save it to some xml? Any code example?

Comment: You can use Json.Net http://www.newtonsoft.com/json which is able to serialize private members aswell. Howto: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24106986/json-net-force-serialization-of-all-private-fields-and-all-fields-in-sub-classe

Comment: The XmlSerializer type complains about these things even if you only intend to serialize objects with it, and never deserialize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON.NET would be the answer here.  You can find it in nuget.  Use it like this:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(input);
```

Comment: I use "string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objectToWrite, seetings);"
I get json as string. How can I convert it to JObject? I have tried:JObject obj = JObject.Parse(json); but it doesn't work.