# Interface properties not getting serialized

Tags: f#, json.net

If I defined a record that implements an interface with an additional property the interface properties are not serialized by json.net. How do I get json.net to serialize those interface properties. Here is an example

```
open Newtonsoft.Json

type IRecord =
    abstract member id : string

type ARec = {
    Name : string
} with
    interface IRecord with
        member this.id = this.Name

let aRec = {Name = "John"}
```

Both `JsonConvert.SerializeObject aRec` and `JsonConvert.SerializeObject (aRec :> IRecord)` result in `{"Name":"John"}` but I expected `{"Name":"John"; "id":"John"}`

I tried adding `ShouldSerializeid` to the interface but that made no difference.

Comment: Well all interfaces are explicitly implemented in f# so it would seem like the solution to [Is it possible to json-serialize a class with explicitly implemented interface properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45608948), which is to apply `[JsonProperty]`, should work here also... but it does not, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/jrXdqh.  As best I can tell f# seems to implement them as *methods* rather than *properties*.  Compare with a c# port of the fiddle above here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/xGImSQ and you will see that the f# type `ARec` has only one property while the c# type has two.