# Why The CosmosDB save only public Members?

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

I have test class which contains some protected and private member:

```
    public class Doc_PrivateValues : Document
    {
        public int PublicIntProperty { get; set; }
        public int PublicIntField;

        protected int ProtectedIntProperty { get; set; }
        protected int ProtectedIntField;

        private int PrivateIntProperty { get; set; }
        private int PrivateIntField;

        public SimpleDocument PublicDocument;
        protected SimpleDocument ProtectedDocument;
        private SimpleDocument PrivateDocument;

        public SimpleStruct PublicStruct;
        protected SimpleStruct ProtectedStruct;
        private SimpleStruct PrivateStruct;
    }
```

I save this document into CosmosDB in very Simple Way:

```
        Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Document result = CosmosClient.CreateDocumentAsync( CosmosCollection.SelfLink, document ).Result.Resource;
        document.id = result.Id;
```

And the result in database:

```
{
    "PublicIntField": 2,
    "PublicDocument": {
        "StrVal": "seven",
        "IntVal": 7,
        "id": null
    },
    "PublicStruct": {
        "StrVal": "ten",
        "IntVal": 10
    },
    "PublicIntProperty": 1,
    "id": "58f18ccf-9e0c-41a6-85cd-a601f12a120a",
    "_rid": "mPlfANiOud4BAAAAAAAAAA==",
    "_self": "dbs/mPlfAA==/colls/mPlfANiOud4=/docs/mPlfANiOud4BAAAAAAAAAA==/",
    "_etag": "\"00000000-0000-0000-8b2a-d853688c01d4\"",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "_ts": 1543856923
}
```

The Document is contains only the public members.
How can I save the Non public members as well?

Thx!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JSON.NET doesn't have access to non public properties, that's why it can't process them. It simply can't see them.

What you can do is to write your own `ContractResolver` which uses reflection to get the non public properties.

Then you can simply provide the `JsonSerializerSettings` on either the `DocumentClient` or the operation level.

The way to do that is described here: [JSON.Net: Force serialization of all private fields and all fields in sub-classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24106986/json-net-force-serialization-of-all-private-fields-and-all-fields-in-sub-classe)

Comment: @GyörgyGulyás You can also accept it as the answer :)