# Excluding a field or property from serialization based on some condition

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I've been reading the JSON.NET [documentation on serialization](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/SerializationAttributes.htm), but what I'm looking for is not in their.

I have an application that messages over the wire that describe business transactions and queries ([commands](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91) and [queries](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92)). Those messages are sent as JSON and we use JSON.NET to serialize and deserialize those objects. Here's an example of such object:

```
public UploadDocumentCommand
{
    public Guid DocumentId;
    public byte[] Data;
}
```

Now on the server we create a audit trail by simply saving these objects to a database table and we store the object in JSON format in the table.

Although most objects contain just a few bytes of data, a few of our objects contain a large amount of data, as can be seen in the previous `UploadDocumentCommand` example (users will send files and images of multiple MBs per command). Although we do want to store those specific commands in the audit trail too we need to prevent that actual data from being serialized and stored in our database, because we will be unable to handle a database of that size.

Usually you would do this by marking the property or field with either an `[JsonIgnoreAttribute]` attribute or an `[NonSerialized]` attribute, byt that will not work in our case, since that would also prevent the data from being sent from client to server, since we use JSON as communication format from client to server as well.

Is there a way to mark these class members in a way that allows us to serialize them conditionally? For instance with a (custom) attribute and a custom configuration in `JsonConvert.SerializeObject`?

Comment: You can create a custom *ContractResolver* similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22042306/determining-properties-to-serialize-in-json-net-based-on-user

Comment: I never was able to close my own question that quickly :-)